# javascript function structure

Tags: javascript

this is an exmaple.

```
var x=5;
var y=x.multiplied(6); // return y=30;
```

how to create a function like `.multiplied()` function on js?

the function structure is like this

```
var1.doSomething(var2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function myInteger( setVal ) {
 this.value = setVal;
}

myInteger.prototype.multiple( mult ) {
 return this.value * mult;
 // Or
 // return new myInteger( this.value * mult );
}

var x = new myInteger(5)
var y = x.multiple(6);
```

Comment: do i have to specify the variable like this ar x = new myInteger(5)? can't i just specify var=5; like another js function?...

Comment: if you specify it like var foo = 5; it will use built-in type integer( and AFAIK there is no way to bind function to integer ) - so only solution is to create own prototypes - objects, made exactly by your needs

Comment: you CAN extend built-in types through their prototypes.. i.e. Number.prototype.foo = function(){} or String.prototype.trim = function(){ ... }

Answer (score 1):

need to extend Number object like this..

```
var x = Number(5);
Number.prototype.multiplied = function(a) {return this * a;};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create fn like multiplied, you need to extend the prototype of a particular type in the following case you need to extend a Native type i.e.

```
Number.prototype.multiplied = function(n){
    return this*n;
}

var x=5; //x is a Number
var y=x.multiplied(6); // return this*6 => this is x => that is 5 => 5*6 = 30;
```

in general, if you have var1.doSomething(var2); and var1 is an object, you could define 'methods' in this way

```
function myObject(name){
   if(!(this instanceof myObject)){ // in the case you're missing 'new' when you declare a myObject instance
       return new myObject(name); 
   }
   this.name = name; //field
   this.doSomething = function(param){ //method
        alert('done '+param+' '+this.name);
   }
}
var var1 = new myObject('peter');
var var2 = "string";
var1.doSomething(var2); //alerts "done string peter"

var var3 = myObject('jean'); //don't need 'new'
var var4 = "homework";
var3.doSomething(var4); //alerts "done homework jean"
```

var1 could also be a general 'library', and you could define it in this way:

```
var var1 = {
    doSomething : function(param){
       alert('done ' + param);
    }
}
//you don't need to instantiate a new object. You have a static library
var var2 = "mystring";
var1.doSomething(var2); //alerts "done mystring"
```